# ¿Cómo puedo mantener mi conexión de VPN estable?

Tags: vpn, rdp

Alguien sabe cómo puedo mantener mi conexión de VPN estable ya he revisado la conexión a la red.

En mi casa yo cuento con dos monitores pero por alguna extraña razón cuando apagan el monitor secundario en la oficina mi escritorio remoto se pone lento como puedo evitar esto?

Si al apagar el monitor secundario voy al 50% si apagan el principal perdería la conexión completa?

Comment: no se como calificar esta pregunta... tu monitor no se que tendra que ver con tu vpn... me parece que no va con el sitio, mas alla que faltaria mucha info

Comment: Estás seguro que no hay otro factor distinto al de los monitores encendidos / apagados para que te afecte la red? Es que no tienen ningún sentido lo que dices. Y menos que por apagar un monitor vayas al 50% (y mucho menos que apagar dos pierdas la conexión)